# Why can't I access Heroku configuration in node?

Tags: node.js, heroku

Using the command line I set a configuration variable in Heroku

```
heroku config:set MONGOLAB_URI=...
```

In node I want to access that variable, so I'm using the following code

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
   dbURI = process.env.MONGOLAB_URI;
}
```

On the terminal I run `NODE_ENV=production nodemon` and the error is that `MONGOLAP_URL` is undefined. However when I run `heroku config` `MONGOLAP_URL` is there.

I also logged `process` and `process.env` and heroku's variable is no where. I also created few other variables with `heroku config:set` to test it fully, and non of them show when I log `process`

The [Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#define-config-vars) state the exact same thing as I have been doing.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be typing `MONGOLAP_URL` when the variable is actually `MONGOLAB_URL`.